# Nifi 1.10.0-Using the new Stateless NiFi execution engine and command line

Tags: apache-nifi, stateless, stateful

[image]

Got this feature,and there are two execution engine now---STATELESS AND STATEFUL,but i am not sure which scenarios do they fit separately?
When i wanna update one or more parameter conveniently,use steteless execution engine and command line?If i need to view the state of flow,use stateful execution engine in Nifi UI?

ANY HELP IS APPRECIATE!

Comment: I have tried to explain, if after reading my answers you don't think "Yes that is exactly what I have been waiting for" you probably just need the regular Nifi mode.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer:
If you want to work interactively in Nifi and develop flows, perhaps define parameters, use the regular Nifi mode.

If you want to run normal flows in a cluster also use the regular Nifi mode.

However, if you have a very linear flow that meets certain restrictions (such as having only 1 source and sink and clearly defined configuration parameters), specifically don't want to acknowledge a message till it completed the flow, and don't want to run it on a cluster but with isolated resources... Then look into the stateless Nifi mode.